# Saving wordpress settings api options with ajax,

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have been wrestling with this problem for quite some time now. 
I have an options page for a theme, and a single option registered.

I have been trying to get the option updated via ajax every time a user presses the save button, here is my code.

JS:

```
       function save_main_options_ajax() {

        $('.main-options-form').submit( function () { 

            var b       =  $(this).serialize(),
                optdata =  { action : "wp_ajax_main_options_save", data: b };

            $.post( ajaxurl, b, function (response) {
                if (response == 1 ) { alert('sucess'); }
                else { alert(optdata);}
            });
            return false;               
        });
    }
save_main_options_ajax();
```

The php:

```
 function main_options_save_ajax() { 

        check_ajax_referer('_wpnonce', '_wpnonce' );

        $data = $_POST;
        unset($data['option_page'], $data['action'], $data['_wpnonce'], $data['_wp_http_referer']);


        if ( update_option('main_options', $data ) )
        { die(1); }
        else { die (0); }           
}
add_action('wp_ajax_main_options_save', 'main_options_save_ajax' );
```

The response i see in firebug is 0. Im not sure what im missing here, i have tried this with some variations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: did you try `echo '1'` and `echo '2'` instead of `die`?

Comment: oops, dont know how that happened, must not have been thinking straight, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: `die` is an language construct equivalent to `exit` which uses the `integer argument` as a exit status and doesn't print that.

Comment: hmm, so you are saying that using die in this instance is pointless?

Comment: really, i did not know that, i shall try it without it, however examples of similar implementations like the one i am trying to do here, all use die() at the end of them. Like this man for example 

[link](http://return-true.com/2010/01/using-ajax-in-your-wordpress-theme-admin/comment-page-2/)

edit: i removed die() from my function, i still met with failure, unfortunately.

Comment: Nop actually I mixed `die` and `exit`, try it with `die('1')` and `die('0')`. That may work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found a way to save settings via ajax when using Settings API.

The main mistake that i made in my code is that i used the wrong url path.

Instead of using the standard `ajaxurl` which is what you would usually use when making ajax calls in wordpress; we use the action call of your settings api form, which is `options.php`.

Because we use this url path, there is no need for a php function to handle the request as options.php handles all of this for us.

Therefore we only need to handle the js function which looks like this in my instance.

```
 function save_main_options_ajax() {
           $('.main-options-form').submit( function () {
                var b =  $(this).serialize();
                $.post( 'options.php', b ).error( 
                    function() {
                        alert('error');
                    }).success( function() {
                        alert('success');   
                    });
                    return false;    
                });
            }
 save_main_options_ajax();
```

That is it, after saving i got the success alert, and my options were saved.

**Note:** There is only one peculiarity that I noticed. After finishing the `POST` request, and showing the success alert, the page makes a `GET` request for a page version of your options page which has the parameters `&settings-updated=true` added onto the end of the url.

I don't know if this is something to be worried about, I have not encountered any problems, but it could be something to consider in the long run.

Comment: Should be notet that by default WordPress runs jQuery in non-conflict mode. Therefore you should change `$` to `jQuery`

Comment: Hi Thanks @Alex for the info. Can i use these functions from plugins file? Currently i am using this function but data is not saving in wp_options table

Comment: Did you manage to make it work without that redirect caused by &settings-updated=true?

Comment: This code worked for me, however, it won't save data which is input from TinyMCE editor fields. Do you know why this would be?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change action value from `wp_ajax_main_options_save` to `main_options_save`. Wordpress adds the prefix `wp_ajax_` to your action value automatically like `wp_ajax_{your_posted_action}`.

Read 5 excellent tips [here](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/) for additional best practises.