# What are the best practices to use AJAX with settings API in Wordpress?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my Wordpress Admin, I have my theme options set-up using the Settings API. I am trying to save the theme options form using Ajax so that the page does not refresh. The only thing i needed to add was this jQuery code :

```
$("#cgform").submit(function() {
var form_data = $('#cgform input').serializeArray();
$.post( 'options.php', form_data ).error(function() {
        alert('error');
    }).success( function() {
        alert('success');   
    });
return false; 
});
```

I wanted to know if doing this is safe? I know the settings api takes care of the nonce fields but I want to be sure if doing this is safe and secure. It would be great if someone can guide me with the "best practices" for using settings api with Ajax.

Comment: my mistake here's a similar question, user only found one issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873537/saving-wordpress-settings-api-options-with-ajax

Comment: I have already gone through the mentioned question. The difference is that the user is saving options via `update_option()` and not the options.php file. I am new to ajax and php so please forgive my ignorance

Comment: you should be fine, jquery has changed `.success`,`.error` and `.complete` to `.done`,`.fail` and `.always` respectively.. you can make sure a person using the ajax has certain permissions, but i dont see any glaring issues.